# Javascript Tic Tac Toe AI - not selecting optimum space

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I have been struggling with creating the unbeatable AI for the Tic Tac Toe project.

I have been googling & using The Coding Train tutorial - however, the AI appears to still be selecting a random square. **Although there must be logic behind which square it is choosing, I can't work out what the logic is!**

Here is my codepen - https://codepen.io/kath-ldn/pen/oNLZqrp , and I have copied the relevant bits of code below.

If anyone could take a look at this I would be so grateful. I have been stuck for quite a few days now and can’t work out what the issue is.

```
//functions to assess winning combos
function equals3(a, b, c) {
    return a === b && b === c && a !== "";
}

function checkWinner(){
    let winner = null;

    if (equals3(gameBoard[0], gameBoard[1], gameBoard[2])) {
        winner = gameBoard[0];
    };
    if (equals3(gameBoard[3], gameBoard[4], gameBoard[5])) {
        winner = gameBoard[3];
    };
    if (equals3(gameBoard[6], gameBoard[7], gameBoard[8])) {
        winner = gameBoard[6];
    };
    if (equals3(gameBoard[0], gameBoard[3], gameBoard[6])) {
        winner = gameBoard[0];
    };
    if (equals3(gameBoard[1], gameBoard[4], gameBoard[7])) {
        winner = gameBoard[1];
    };
    if (equals3(gameBoard[2], gameBoard[5], gameBoard[8])) {
        winner = gameBoard[0];
    };
    if (equals3(gameBoard[0], gameBoard[4], gameBoard[8])) {
        winner = gameBoard[0];
    };
    if (equals3(gameBoard[2], gameBoard[4], gameBoard[6])) {
        winner = gameBoard[2];
    };

    let openSpots = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
        if (gameBoard[i] === "") {
            openSpots = openSpots + 1;
        };
    };

    if (winner === null && openSpots === 0) {
        return 'tie';
    } else {
        return winner;
    };
};

let scores = {
  X: 10,
  O: -10,
  tie: 0
};

//function to create impossible-to-beat AI using minimax algorithm
function bestMove() {
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    let move;
    for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
      if (gameBoard[i] === "") {
        gameBoard[i] = AI;
        let score = minimax(gameBoard, 0, false);
        gameBoard[i] = "";
        if (score > bestScore) {
        bestScore = score;
        move = i;
        }
      }    
    }
    gameBoard[move] = AI;
};

//minimax function
function minimax(gameBoard, depth, isMaximizing){
  let result = checkWinner();
  if (result !== null) {
    return scores[result];
  }

  if (isMaximizing) {
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
      if (gameBoard[i] === "") {
        gameBoard[i] = AI;
        let score = minimax(gameBoard, depth + 1, false);
        gameBoard[i] = "";
        bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
      }
    }
    return bestScore;
  } else {
    let bestScore = Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
      if (gameBoard[i] === "") {
        gameBoard[i] = human;
        let score = minimax(gameBoard, depth + 1, true);
        gameBoard[i] = "";
        bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
      }
    }
    return bestScore;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through the board and calling minimax for each square, this is not necessary and will be super slow. You just need to call it once like this:

```
move, score = minimax(gameBoard, 8, true)
```

I am not sure if it is needed, but I would return a 0 from the checkWinner function instead of returning a 'tie' string. It seems hard to chose a max/min valie from e.g. a 1 and a 'te' otherwise.

Then in your minimax function you need to change a few things to actually return the best move it finds. Sorry for any programming language issues, I am used to Python. I hope you get what I mean anyway:

```
//minimax function
function minimax(gameBoard, depth, isMaximizing){
  let result = checkWinner();
  if (result !== null) {
    return None, scores[result];
  }

  if (isMaximizing) {
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
      if (gameBoard[i] === "") {
        gameBoard[i] = AI;
        let score = minimax(gameBoard, depth - 1, false)[1];
        gameBoard[i] = "";
        if score > bestScore:
            bestScore = score
            bestMove = gameBoard[i]
      }
    }
    return bestMove, bestScore;
  } else {
    let bestScore = Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++) {
      if (gameBoard[i] === "") {
        gameBoard[i] = human;
        let score = minimax(gameBoard, depth - 1, true)[1];
        gameBoard[i] = "";
        if score < bestScore:
            bestScore = score
            bestMove = gameBoard[i]
      }
    }
    return bestMove, bestScore;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, much appreciated! I used this (and looked at a different tutorial) and now have something that works. It is at the same codepen link in case anyone else is stuck on the same thing and stumbles across this page.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please accept the answer if you are happy with the solution (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)